independent reservoir sampling using DuckDB
The following concerns the current release of DuckDB (V1.1.4).
Contrast the following uses of random() and reservoir(), where
reservoir() is defined as:
create or replace function reservoir() as (
  FROM range(0,5)
  USING SAMPLE 1
) ;

Using random(), we can use a CTE to achieve independent calls to random():
with recursive cte as (
  select 0 as ix, random() as r
  union all
  select ix+1, random() as r
  from cte
  where ix< 5
  )
  from cte;

┌───────┬─────────────────────┐
│  ix   │          r          │
│ int32 │       double        │
├───────┼─────────────────────┤
│     0 │  0.2980559015344461 │
│     1 │ 0.13979473511213986 │
│     2 │ 0.37514631745771243 │
│     3 │  0.6884955062958484 │
│     4 │  0.4000883881057728 │
│     5 │  0.6894718306734245 │
└───────┴─────────────────────┘

BUT when we call reservoir() instead:
with recursive cte as (
  select 0 as ix, reservoir() as r
  union all
  select ix+1, reservoir() as r
  from cte
  where ix< 5
  )
  from cte;

┌───────┬───────┐
│  ix   │   r   │
│ int32 │ int64 │
├───────┼───────┤
│     0 │     3 │
│     1 │     3 │
│     2 │     3 │
│     3 │     3 │
│     4 │     3 │
│     5 │     3 │
└───────┴───────┘

This contrasting behavior reflects the fact that the stability of the
two functions is set differently:
SELECT function_name, stability
FROM duckdb_functions()
WHERE function_name IN ('random', 'reservoir');
┌───────────────┬───────────┐
│ function_name │ stability │
│    varchar    │  varchar  │
├───────────────┼───────────┤
│ random        │ VOLATILE  │
│ reservoir     │ NULL      │
└───────────────┴───────────┘

Since it does not seem to be currently possible to change the stability attribute
of DuckDB-defined functions using the DuckDB language,
my question is whether there is a way to achieve independent calls to reservoir() in DuckDB without using a hosting language such as Python.

Which version of duckdb are you using? It seems to be working for me - it does return different values.

@roman - v1.1.4-dev3247.  I hadn't realized there's been a change.  One of the main developers of DuckDB has indicated the behavior described above is intended.
